# Inline assembly explanation

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I'm trying to port a project from Windows to Linux.
I host the code in the following repo: [Nspire Emu](https://github.com/antoniovazquezblanco/nspire_emu).
I was able to fix some compilation errors but a lot of functions need to be reimplemented and there are some parts I'm not able understand.

`frame` variable type definition:

```
typedef struct { void *prev, *function; } os_exception_frame_t;
```

Piece of inline assemble I don't understand:

```
asm ("movl %%fs:(%1), %0" : "=r" (frame->prev) : "r" (0));

asm ("movl %0, %%fs:(%1)" : : "r" (frame), "r" (0));
```

I would really appreciate if anyone would help me understand the previous code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The gcc and the visual c compilers have different syntax for inline assembly. I would start with the docs from the compiler it works correctly under and translate to the format required by the compiler you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This was compiled in Linux with mingw gcc, this means I'm able to compile the code both in Windows and Linux. Thats not the problem for me. The problem is the actual meaning of that piece of code. I've recently found that fs:0 is where SEH takes place in Windows and now I know what that code does. See http://feepingcreature.github.io/handling.html Thanks for time and patience and sorry for answering my own question. PD: I cant answer because of my reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inline asm is popping a windows exception handler frame from the structured exception handler stack.  Linux doesn't use structured exception handlers, so this code needs to be removed for linux and replaced by something completely different that does the same thing.  What that is depends on what the code is trying to achieve by manipulating the SEH stack.  The equivalent in Linux likely involves registering some signal handlers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've started reading about this. http://feepingcreature.github.io/handling.html